# Which process(es) controls the keyboad backlit and the touch bar?

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar, backlight

Something crasched or hung on my Macbook Pro 16" (intel) and now they keyboard backlit is off while the touchpad is on but doesn't react on input. I would like to restart all processes controlling these features but haven't found any obvious candidates.

What is/are the name(s) of the processes controlling the keyboard backlit and the touch bar?

Comment: Is there a reason you just can't restart the system? That's the first step in troubleshooting computer problems....

Comment: @SteveChambers It depends on the purpose. A restart might fix it but then you don't know what caused it to start with, and the problem might happen again.

Comment: A restart fixes almost no recurring problems, but what it does do is (often) fix the current issue long enough for you to get the work done and verify that the issue is (likely) in software. Thus making it the first step in troubleshooting an issue.